# ECMAScript class properties not possible in vue electron application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, electron, babeljs

I'm developing a vue application that runs in electron. For ease of setup I'm using vue-cli with the [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder).

I created the project using:

```
vue create
```

made sure to check `babel` in the feature select

added the electron packages using:

```
vue add electron-builder
```

and created a class in `foo.js`:

```js
export class Foo {
  foo = "Hello";
}
```

Now, when importing that class in the generated `main.js` (where the Vue instance gets created) I can use

```
npm run electron:serve
```

to run the application in electron. It opens up, shows no errors, all as expected.

But if I try and import the `Foo` class in the generated `background.js` (where the electron windows gets created) and run `npm run electron:serve` it shows me this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

 error  in ./src/foo.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export class Foo {
>   foo = "Hello";
| }
|

 @ ./src/background.js 9:0-28
 @ multi ./src/background.js
```

According to the README from the [github page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app) for @vue/babel-preset-app
it should use the `plugin-proposal-class-properties`. This sounds exactly like
the type of thing that should be used.

I also tried using the `vue.config.js` with `configureWebpack` and told it to use the babel-loader with the vue preset. Same error.

Is there a way for me to use class properties when importing a module in the `background.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for my problem while looking at the [documentation](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#webpack-configuration) for the vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder.

It uses the [webpack-chain](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain) package to configure electron specific bundling.

So instead of using `configureWebpack`in `vue.config.js` I setup my config as described in the example from webpack-chain:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      chainWebpackMainProcess: config => {
        config.module
          .rule("compile")
          .test(/\.js$/)
          .exclude.add(/(node_modules|dist_electron)/)
          .end()
          .use("babel")
          .loader("babel-loader")
          .options({
            presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"]
          });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then the imports work as expected.